# How to invoke a remote taskflow and show it in popup?

Tags: oracle-adf

I need to invoke a remote task flow deployed in different domain and open it in an inline frame(Pop up) in ADF. I [followed](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/43-remote-task-flow-169185.pdf) and it's working with simple page. But when I try to invoke it in a pop up on click of button it is giving 404 Error.

Can some body help me with it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ADF Dialog framework, but in this case it's a little complex.
**First**: Create a new taskflow in the consumer application and place a remote-taskflow-call as the default activity. 
**Second**: Create a taskflow-call-activity formt  the new taskflow on the consumer taskflow .
**Third**, in the properties of the second taskflow-call-activity under Behavior section you can configure set the Run As Dialog property to true, then configure the property Display Type to inline-popup to use an ADF popup or external-window to use a new browser window.
**Finally**: You must configure the action component that calls the second taskflow , in the properties of the action component (for example af:button) under the Behavior section, configure the Secondary Window you'll show, set the porperty UseWindow to true and configure the WindowEmbedStyle, WindowModalityType, and the popup window dimensions.

Here is a simple example about ADF Dialog Framework: http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2013/03/reusable-adf-region-with-dialog.html

If you use parameters, you must send them to the First and from there to the Second taskflow.
Return values in this case are really complicated.

Hope it helps...
Rafael